# Inkscape does not switch languages

Tags: macos, inkscape, xquartz

I installed Inkscape on MBP along with last version of XQuartz.

The keyboard input is stuck on second non-English language and I cannot use any shortcut or input English text. It does not matter that Cmd+Space switches the languages - Inkscape still "see" only one non-English. This question I asked in AskDifferent - no any answer, thus I try to find the solution here.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To switch languages in Inkscape with OSX you should enable it in XQuartz options:

X11 -> Preferences -> Input
Select "Follow system keyboard layout"

Then, if you change keyboard layout with cmd+space, Inkscape language will change too.

Answer (score 0):

Via the [Inkscape FAQ](http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/Frequently_asked_questions):

> *How do I change the interface language?*
>
> Inkscape should follow the settings in System Preferences > International.
>      If it does not that is a bug and you should report it. Alternatively,
>      starting with Inkscape 0.47, you can change the language for Inkscape only
>      in Inkscape's Edit > Preferences > Interface. Inkscape needs to be restarted
>      for the change to take effect.